# How is "winded" pronounced in "he winded a horn"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Either "wɪnd" or "waɪnd" is acceptable, according to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wind), but merely being acceptable doesn't satisfy me. "Wɪnd" seems better to me, due to the connotation of blowing wind, etc, but apparently "waɪnd" is preferred, being listed first.  Which was originally intended?  (Or does it really not matter?)

Comment: Could you please provide a link for your reference at Dictionary.com? [Whynd](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whynd) draws a blank for me.

Comment: @Firstrock He meant the pronunciation, not a word.

Comment: @Firstrock: Hopefully it makes more sense now.  I was up too late last night and didn't have time to follow up too closely till this morning.

Comment: So are you asking which pronunciation was first etymologically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the pronunciations /waind/ and /wihnd/ are used to indicate different verbs. They write:

> Etymology:  < wind n.1 In ordinary prose use the pronunciation is /wɪnd/ except in sense 3, where it is /waɪnd/

The sense 3 that they give is:

> trans. To sound by forcing the breath through, to blow (a wind-instrument, esp. a horn).

So the *wind* in respects to a horn would be *waɪnd*.

Comment: But Dictionary.com allows either.  I suppose it's just being lenient.

Comment: Merriam-Webster online also says that both pronunciations are allowed for the meaning of blowing a horn, as well as both past tenses *winded* and *wound.* They don't say whether both pronunciations of the vowel in *winded* are allowed, but the OED says the preferred past tense is *winded,* pronounced /waɪndəd/, although *wound* is also acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is: was *wind* (blow a musical instrument) originally pronounced like *wind* (wind up a clock) or *wind* (as in wind and rain), I believe the answer is both. Merriam-Webster dates this usage to 1586, shortly before Shakespeare started writing plays. William Shakespeare repeatedly rhymed *wind* (as in wind and rain) with *find* and *kind,* which I assume would also rhyme with *wind* (wind up a clock), as they do today.

> Nor can I fortune to brief minutes tell,
>   Pointing to each his thunder, rain and wind,
>   Or say with princes if it shall go well,
>   By oft predict that I in heaven find:

The pronunciation has changed since, so the sonnet no longer rhymes.

Comment: Ah, so "wind" (that blows) was originally pronounced waɪnd.  That explains why "winding" a horn is pronounced that way, but not why "wind" (that blows) changed pronunciation while "winding" a horn didn't change.

Comment: Well, inertia might have tended to keep the long i in "wind" (blowing a horn), if people perceived these as different words. The real question is why "wind" (that blows) changed pronunciation.

Comment: When did the pronunciation change? I strongly suspect that it changed quite a while before people started using *wound* as the past tense of *wind* (to blow); for these people, the use of *winded* or *wound* was probably determined solely by the pronunciation of *wind*.  Using Google books, I found a use of *wound* (a horn) in 1805, and several uses in the immediately following years. So the pronunciation of *wind* (that blows) changed somewhere between 1600 and 1800. That's still a big gap.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a vowel shift in English.. See.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift
looking at the table, in Shakespeare’s time the “i” was transitioning from /iː/ to /aɪ/ but we do not know if it was still a long vowel or already a diphthong
 /iː/ /ei/  /ɛi/     /aɪ/

Still, this does not explain why in the meaning of “blowing” it remained short, while in the meaning of “turning” it became long..

Comment: Please edit your existing answer rather than adding another.

Answer (score 0):

The horn is a “Wind instrument” and its name derives from the French “instruments à vent”
see Wikipedia

A wind instrument is a musical instrument … in which a column of air is set into vibration by the player blowing into (or over) a mouthpiece …
Whatever the pronunciation was in any year, if “wind” - the one that blows over the land - is pronounced TODAY to rhyme with “sinned”, so should be “wind instrument”, it has nothing to do with the “wind” of e.g. “winding up a clock”.

Comment: Please include some research to back up your claim. Other answers from reputable dictionaries are contrary to this answer.